# Search Result by filter does not find an existing and crawled document

Tags: 2013, search-results, filter, keywordquery

This is related to SP 2013 On-Premises.
We have a custom Search Page and we use Keyword-Query to filter the Result.
The related document which cannot be found by that page has at least two meta data fields assigned (both managed metadata) and can be found by regular search and also by Search-API, like so:

https://company.com/_api/search/query?Querytext='PRDBGerKlasse:"306"'&RowLimit='10'&SelectProperties='Title,Path,PRDBGerKlasse,PRDBGerTyp,PRDBGerArt'

The document has "306" for PRDBGerKlasse and "TypeA 300" for PRDBGerTyp.
When we then call the page by 
https://company.com/search/pages/prdb.aspx**#k=PRDBGerTyp%3aTypeA%20300**

the document is not in the search Result.
If we call the page without the filter, the document can be found.

What could cause such issue?

Please note that we added the item 306 two weeks ago to the relevant Term-Set.
Could that be an issue with the crawler even if the document can be found by regular search?

Comment: Additional finding: When filtering for the new Term-set-Item directly like so: https://company.com/search/pages/prdb.aspx#k=PRDBGerKlasse%3a306, the document is found.

Comment: Additional finding: I captured the query settings from the webpart and realized the language setting of: "SerializedQuery": "<Query Culture="de-DE"...  If I add the culture parameter _api/search/query?culture=1033&Querytext='...., the document will be found. If I add _api/search/query?culture=1031&Querytext='..., the document will not be found. So this is related to language.

Answer (score 0):

The usual suspects are either that the search result web part is set to filter out duplicates or that the max number of items for that web part is less than the actual number

Comment: the webpart is configured to not trim duplicates and max items is not a problem

Answer (score 0):

If your library has more than 5,000 files, search can omit files from results. If that's the case, indexing the column(s) you're querying might help.

Comment: this is not the case

Comment: Can you find other documents using those fields as filters in the keyword query?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be an By-Design-Issue.
Thanks Kasper and Ben for your input.
The Result-Page has a **OOB refinement panel which by design does not support multilingual user interface**. As a cross check, a new web (german) with only result Webpart shows the relevant english document even when I choose 'German' from the language selector of the result Webpart. I already wrote 'If we call the page without the filter, the document can be found' but I wasn't aware of the refiner.
Sorry for waisting your time.